# make canvas sence in es6 classess

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to make my canvas with es6 classes ; I could make it with es5 , but in es6 I have a problem :

```js
let canvas = {
    "myCanvas" : document.querySelector("#myCanvas")
};

let myCan = canvas.myCanvas;

class MyCanvasContext {
    static start() {

        if (myCan.getContext) {
            this.ctx = myCan.getContext('2d');

            this.draw();

        }
        else {
            console.write("Update");
        }
    }

    static draw() {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
        this.ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';
        this.ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Canvas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <main onload="MyCanvasContext.start();">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
         </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

It dosen't show me anything ; What Should I do ???
Without class it works right , and i didn't forget set type as module

Comment: What do you mean by *"and i didn't forget set type as module"*? There's no problem using `class` outside of modules.

Comment: Really ? My teacher said it ; thanks

Comment: That's unfortunate, it isn't remotely correct. :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the `load` event on a `main` element. Only some elements (such as `body`) support a `load` event.

Instead, just ensure your `script` tag is at the end of your document, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and call `MyCanvasContext.start();` directly:

```js
let canvas = {
    "myCanvas" : document.querySelector("#myCanvas")
};

let myCan = canvas.myCanvas;

class MyCanvasContext {
    static start() {
        if (myCan.getContext) {
            this.ctx = myCan.getContext('2d');

            this.draw();

        }
        else {
            console.write("Update");
        }
    }

    static draw() {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
        this.ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';
        this.ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
    }
}

MyCanvasContext.start();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Canvas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <main>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
         </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or, if you really want to wait for the `load` event (which waits for all resources before firing, including all images, etc.), use the `load` event on `window`:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => { MyCanvasContext.start(); });
```

---

Side note: There's not a lot of benefit to using `class` syntax if all of your methods are `static`, and you wouldn't be able to have more than one canvas handled by your class. You might consider using prototype methods instead, passing in the canvas as a construction parameter, like this:

```js
class MyCanvasContext {
    constructor(myCan) {
        if (!myCan.getContext) {
            throw new Error("myCan must be a canvas element");
        }
        this.myCan = myCan;
        this.ctx = this.myCan.getContext("2d");
    }
    start() {
        this.draw();
    }

    draw() {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
        this.ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';
        this.ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
    }
}

const mc = new MyCanvasContext(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));
mc.start();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Canvas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <main>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
         </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks , with your way it's solved ; I'm sorry i have a little problem in speaking english and may br i have a problem

Answer (score 0):

call method on body onLoad

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Canvas</title>
        </head>
        <body onload="MyCanvasContext.start();">
             <main >
                <canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
             </main>

            <script>
                let canvas = {
                    "myCanvas" : document.querySelector("#myCanvas")
                };

                let myCan = canvas.myCanvas;

                class MyCanvasContext {
                    static start() {
                        if (myCan.getContext) {
                            this.ctx = myCan.getContext('2d');

                            this.draw();

                        }
                        else {
                            console.write("Update");
                        }
                    }

                    static draw() {
                        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
                        this.ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

                        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)';
                        this.ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
                    }
                }
    </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```